# Add delete to the Clear List button to remove the list itmes

Tags: javascript, html

How can I add delete to the clear list button to remove the list items? Should declare a variable? What to do? I'm a beginner so maybe I've used the queryselector a lot. Kindly help

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
  document.querySelector('#clear').disabled = true;

  document.querySelector('#todo').onkeyup = () => {
    if (document.querySelector('#todo').value.length > 0)
      document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
    else document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
  };

  document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = () => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#todo').value;

    document.querySelector('#to-dos').append(li);

    document.querySelector('#todo').value = "";

    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
    document.querySelector('#clear').disabled = false;

    document.querySelector("#clear").removeChild('#todo');
    return false;
  };
});
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>

<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Add an item" id="todo" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" />
  <button id="clear">Clear list</button>
</form>

<ol id="to-dos"></ol>
```

Comment: What are "delete properties" supposed to be? (Are you simply asking how to make your "clear" button _working_, or what?)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are "delete properties"? Why are you trying to remove children of the Clear button? It shouldn't have any.

Comment: If you're just asking how to make the Clear button remove the list items, you'll need another event handler for that.

Comment: You can fire this code for delete all of li/todo 

document.querySelectorAll("li").forEach((item) => item.remove());

Comment: Yes I want to remove the list items which were added after submitting. Okay another event handler but I don't know the method which will delete the list items.

Comment: I've got the solution to this. Thank You. Consider it as closed

Answer (score 0):

```js
function removeItem(item){
        var itemToRemove = document.getElementById(item);
        itemToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(itemToRemove);
}
```

```html
var listItemHTML = '<div id="item' + i + '"><input type="checkbox" onclick="crossedOut(\'item' + i + '\');">' + listItem + 
'<input type = "button" value="Remove" onclick="removeItem(\'item' + i + '\');"></div>';
```